# Неправильная работа программы

Tags: c++, структуры, struct

В задаче необходимо вывести имена учащихся без троек, двоек и колов. Однако моя программа выводит имена всех введенных учащихся. В чем проблема?? Вот код

```
  struct st {
        char a[100];
        char b[100];
        int z,y,x;
    };
    int main() {
        int n;
        cin >>n;
        st stud[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> stud[i].a >> stud[i].b;
            cin>>stud[i].x >> stud[i].y>>stud[i].z;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if ((4<=stud[i].x<=5) && (4<=stud[i].y<=5)&&(4<=stud[i].z<=5)) {
                   cout <<stud[i].a <<" " <<stud[i].b << "\n";
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: `4<=stud[i].y<=5` разве не `stud[i].y > 3`?

Comment: @Birdy так и 7, и 8 больше 3

Comment: @Abyx x, y, z - оценки по трем предметам, a,b - имя/фамилия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражения вида

```
(4<=stud[i].x<=5)
```

следует заменить на

```
(stud[i].x >= 4 && stud[i].x <= 5)
```

У вас же получалось, что число сравнивалось с логическим значением (результатом второй операции сравнения).

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю чем Вы собирали программу, но msvc2015 ругается на попытку создания массива на стеке с размером указанным переменной. Поменял на векторы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Student {
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    int z,y,x;
};

bool goodMark(int _mark)
{
    return _mark == 4 || _mark == 5;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<Student> studVec;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Student stItem;

        std::cin >> stItem.a >> stItem.b;
        std::cin >> stItem.x >> stItem.y >> stItem.z;

        studVec.push_back(stItem);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        const Student &stItem = studVec[i];

        if(goodMark(stItem.x) && goodMark(stItem.y) && goodMark(stItem.z))
        {
            std::cout << stItem.a << " " << stItem.b << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```